# How to form ring around circle on hover

Tags: html, css

[image: I want like this. The outer ring. I want it to appear on hover]

```css
.images {
 width: 125px;
 border: 2px solid #FFF;
 border-radius: 100px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.images:hover {
 background: transparent;
 margin-top:4px;
 color: transparent !important;
 border:1px solid #999;
 
 /*{Shadow}*/
 box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px 0 #333;
 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px 0 #333;
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px 0 #333, 0 1px 1px 0 #fff;

}
```

```html
<img src="pic_mountain.jpg" class="images" alt="Save icon"/>
```

I want ring around my circular image on hover. I dont want border to my image. I want ring which is little away from image. How do i do this with css?

Comment: Where’s your code?

Comment: add some code, more explanations for your purpose, a little idea and so on.. in order to get real answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circle with two borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305594/circle-with-two-borders)

Comment: I am not getting how to add image in snippet

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/43erktx0/

Answer (score 2):

```css
body{
  padding: 50px;
  background: #fff;
}
div{
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #004080;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
div:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 70% 70%;
  background: #b5cacf; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b5cacf 0%, #5c86ac 50%, #004080 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b5cacf 0%,#5c86ac 50%,#004080 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b5cacf 0%,#5c86ac 50%,#004080 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b5cacf', endColorstr='#004080',GradientType=0 );
}
div:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 0 7px #0A5ACB;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: thank you.. But how to make inner space transparent. when i am changing box shadow 5px #fff to transparent. It is not apperaing

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your picture in a bigger div and put a border on it, with `border-radius:50%;`