# CSS circle - possible to add a transparent gap between border and background color?

Tags: css

I am creating a circle with CSS, I would like to have a gap between the border of the circle and the background color so that you can see through to the background. Is this possible?

```css
.container {
  background:url('https://picsum.photos/536/354');
}
.circle {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:50px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Desired result:

[image]

Comment: Not exactly. OP need **transparent** space..

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I cannot do a double border with `box-shadow` because I need the gap to be transparent so that the image behind it is visible through the gap

Comment: @MoshFeu the second answer on the duplicated one shows how to do it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34438447/8732818)

Comment: @CalvinNunes you're right

Comment: @CalvinNunes yep, my bad. I actually found that question as well but didn't read past the accepted answer :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with a pseudo element (`.circle::after`)  and the following (or similar) settings:

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/536/354');
}

.circle {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: calc(100% + 16px);
  height: calc(100% + 16px);
  left: -8px;
  top: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pseudo element (`:before` for example) to add a transparent "layer" with border. Use `translate` to place it in more generic way (so if you'll change the size of it, it will be in the right place).

Like this:

```css
.container {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/536/354');
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: red;
}

.circle:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
  height: calc(100% + 10px);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

not that straight forward but with one element:

```css
.container {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/536/354');
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.circle::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```